# Left headphone have significantly lower volume than right one - Macbook Pro 2012

Tags: audio, headphones, sound-volume

After upgrading SSD and traveling with my Macbook Pro and traveling while low temperatures outside (I don't know if this is relevant).

When I connect headphones the sound on the left one is significantly quieter.

Is it connector problem or not ? Should I try to put something to the hole, and bent a little bit connectors ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I found out it was volume setting problem, that could be changed in "Audio MIDI setup"

Plug in the headphones (if there is problem with headphones - if problem exists when using internal speakers, don't plug headphones)

Find in Spotlight "Audio MIDI setup" app:

[image: Results from Spotlight]

And open app :

[image: Audio MIDI setup app, wrong settings]

Make sure that channel 1 and 2 have THE SAME volume set up. Set every channel to value "1" as here :

[image: Audio MIDI setup app, appropriate settings]

I have no idea how this disproportion in volume happened. But I would like to know. (I haven't tinker with volume before - except simple volume up/down via headphone control or keyboard's function keys)

This answer is based on the "The Hefster's" answer from :

https://discussions.apple.com/message/18797385#18797385

[image: The Heftster's answer from Apple Discussion page]
(I post screenshot because https://discussions.apple.com doesn't support linking to stand alone posts)

Comment: This is awesome. I had something similar happen and it took quite some time to figure out why one channel was attenuated.

Comment: If anybody would be able to "extract" problem, it would be nice to post it to https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: For what it is worth: setting the two channels to the same value sounds a little off to me. Your 18.5dB difference is pretty big, but after listening to a few tracks I settled on a 3dB increase on channel 2. (all proper disclaimers about your milage may vary etc. &c. )

Comment: I experience this again today on Yosemite. Still I have no idea of the cause of it.

Comment: You are a saint!!! I thought I was going crazy / losing hearing.

Comment: Same on Yosemite. Lucky I found this thread.

Comment: Geez! I've been having this problem for months or years (almost nothing from left channel) and assumed the jack itself was broken.  To just drag that slider and have it fixed is as disgusting as it is fantastic.  2009 13" MBP.

Comment: Thanks for the tip: I have the same problem (left is SIGNIFICANTLY louder then right, so with this fix - everything is very quiet) - definitely not a jack issue. The imbalance is always the same in both cases: when headphones are attached directly to macbook audio jack AND when they're attached via docking station, which is attached via thunderbolt port. So it has to be a sound card or software issue. Considering how many people are having this issue - it looks like apple's production, QC or design flaw.

Comment: Notice that you can achieve the same effect by changing Settings->Sound: Balance. Also, to quickly exclude hearing impairment as a cause, wearing headphones upside down with right/left switched is a simple test. Finally, encountering the same problem on two different Macs (with balance always at neutral already), let me trace the problem to just headphone plug/cable--unless MacOS does something weird cross-machine...

Comment: This helped me solve a balance issue. The sound was suddenly markedly lower on one side of my headsets after I plugged them in while adjusting the volume of the inbuilt speakers. Arigatou!

Comment: 2022 and the issue still exists. if I change the volume the balance changes as well

Answer (score 1):

Weird solution but it worked for me. I noticed one of the 'holes' of my right EarPod played sound a lot softer than the others did. In my rather desperate attempt at getting it to work properly again, I tried blowing and sucking in to it. It did the job, hopefully it will for you as well.

Comment: Haha I was already trying the balance MIDI solution, but first - be sure to clean your earbuds from all dirt and earwax - it truly made a huge difference for me :/